# Is it possible to fire an event when a user leaves a Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I've looked through the docs, so forgive me if this is written down somewhere. Is it possible to do something like window.onunload for a Lightning component? window.onunload (or .onbeforeunload) both work for the user refreshing the page or going to a different site, but I can't get an event to fire if they navigate to a different component within a Lightning app (I want to track time spent using certain components).

Comment: FYI, I stumbled across this post when trying to capture when a user attempts to leave a lightning component by clicking a different tab in Lightning Experience - the senior program architect from salesforce here confirmed with sfdc product management that this is currently not possible, but may be in the near future

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you call a function in the button you're using to close the component?

If you're using a close button or a navigation button that ends the component you can call a function on that button.

Comment: I considered that, but I'd also like to capture when a user leaves the page or closes the browser window (to be able to track time spent on component as well as prompt a user if they have unsaved edits).

Comment: Well, to track de time you can just create a time script.

Comment: the time* And for the unsaved edits you could call the function on the button